# How to compare 2 objects' private member?

Tags: c++

I have 2 class:

```
class A
{
    int aa;
};
class B
{
    int bb;
};
class C
{
    public:
        bool equal(A& av,B& bv)
        {
            return (av.aa==bv.bb);
        }
};
```

Of course, class C has compilation error cause of private members' access.
Is there a way to implement that `equal()` member of class C ?

Comment: The OOP way: create accessor methods for `aa` and `bb` and read a tutorial on OOP and encapsulation. The hackish way: make them public / make C a friend class / stop using classes altogether / etc.

Comment: @MihaiTodor Accessors aren't OOP. Better to tie behaviour and and data together. Create a class with `aa` and `bb` and whatever behaviour depends upon their equality.

Comment: Another way of making the member variables of `A` and `B` public, is to declare `A` and `B` as `struct` instead of `class`.

Comment: Is there any kind of relation between `A` and `B`? Should they perhaps be derived from a common base class (in which case the problem may not occur)? Or could the data members be made public (encapsulation is many cases not actually useful)? Do other functions/classes also need access?

Comment: @Peter I can think of several scenarios where you would want accessors. In this simple example, indeed, they are pointless, but I guess his code is more complex.

Comment: What's the real design goal you're trying to achieve here? Taken at face value, this looks like a very bizarre request.

Comment: @MihaiTodor [Tell, Don't Ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask)

Comment: @MihaiTodor: You are extending the common misconception that friendship is a hack and that providing accessors is better. It is not. When you provide an accessor you are making public the state of your object to *everyone*. When you declare a class a friend, you grant access to your internals to *only* that class. Of course, as everything else, friendship can be abused --it should only be used within already highly coupled types--, but making the fields public or providing accessors is more often than not a worse decision.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That's a nice point. I agree with it, and most of the times, methods should be designed to provide more functionality, rather than just exposing a private member, but, on the other hand, creating a friend dependency between classes in order to hack around a bad design is also undesirable.

Comment: It's worth noting that if instances of two types are capable of "being equal", that pretty much means the types are highly coupled. Equality is not a very abstract property. If you can't handle the equality via a common base type, then it's probably appropriate that whatever function or class compares then, is coupled to both classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great scenario for using `friend` functions:

```
// forwarding references to each of the classes
class A;
class B;
class C
{
public:
    bool equal(A& av,B& bv);
    // notice we cannot implement equal() here, 
    // because A and B have not been defined yet, 
    // even though they have been declared.
};

class A
{
private:
    int aa;

    // Simply register to be a friend of A with our 'C::equal' function,
    // so that we can access 'aa' 
    friend bool C::equal(A&, B&);
};
class B
{
private:
    int bb;

    // Once again, we register as a friend of C::equal,
    // this time to access 'bb'
    friend bool C::equal(A&, B&);
};

// finally, now that A and B have been fully defined,
// we can implement our equal method:
bool C::equal(A&av, B&bv)
{
    return (av.aa == bv.bb);
}

// Sample Usage
int main()
{
    A a = A();
    B b = B();

    C c = C();

    c.equal(a, b);
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter explain? This example compiles fine, and works for what the OP requested.

Comment: If there is really a valid reason to want to keep the members unaccessible and, nevertheles, want to compare them, this is the way. Though I cannot think of such a reason.

Comment: I cannot think of a reason either. You want to publicly compare two objects based on properties which aren't accessible. Its like saying that two black boxes contains the same thing, while not being able to say what is in a black box from outside. Even if c++ allows it is pretty weird

Comment: @UmNyobe well, C++ is weird. I guess we just have to accept that :)

Comment: @Gorpik: With the description in the question it is impossible to tell, but there are good uses of friendship.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas my favorite usage of friendship is to skip down the beach with my partnering class :)

Comment: Some good examples: `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr` the object that holds the reference count is an implementation detail of *both*, but one type may need to access the count of another, and you don't want to make the count public to everyone. A container and the iterators, surely you don't want the implementation details of the container public, but the iterator *needs* to access them. Note that the common pattern is that both types are **highly coupled** already (friendship is the highest coupling relationship in the language, more so than inheritance).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas There are indeed good uses for friendship. In fact, I upvoted this answer. I just wanted to remark that there may be a better solution for OP's problem though, as you say, it is impossible to tell from this question.

Comment: @UmNyobe: I'd go further than that, it's like saying that a red box and a green box contain the same thing and therefore "are the same", while not being able to see what's in either box. Clearly whatever does that comparison knows something that the person calling it cannot know, i.e. it's more tightly coupled to the RedBox and GreenBox classes.

Comment: Yes!! That's what I want !
Forget any getter/setter function about A and B class, it **breaks goal of encapsulation**. Forget ancestor class, too. It just makes classes **go to mess**. Thanks to Richard, you give us a lesson.

Answer (score 10):

A good solution might be to provide getters in A and B classes. 
This way you keep everything encapsulated. 
e.g.

```
class A
{
    int aa;
    public:
     int GetAA()
     {
       return aa ;
     }

};
```

Comment: When you provide an accessor you are effectively leaking details of your implementation to all the world. Sometimes they are a solution (the size of a vector is a public property, everyone should be able to read it), in others it will be a horrible idea (the count object in a shared pointer is an implementation detail even if weak pointers need access to it, which is why there is a friendship relationship). Providing an accessor is **not** keeping everything encapsulated, but on the contrary breaking encapsulation.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I understand where you are coming from. But in this case should it be a problem? Only a copy of the primitive will be made, so you can't overwrite the data.

Comment: @LewsTherin: it is a problem when at some point, A doesn't need aa anymore (e.g. refactored to another class), but users already use GetAA()

Comment: @stefaanv: then you'd try to re-implement `GetAA()` to get the value from wherever it has been refactored to, and if you can't do that you're in trouble. But sure, `GetAA` shouldn't be added as "a means to access `aa`", it should only be added in the first place if it makes sense for the type `A` to have an integer property that users of the class would want to see.

Comment: I'm reading more about accessors now. There is clearly a lot I still need to learn about. When you are used to writing in C#, properties or getters become part of you :(. As I said in my answer  it might be a good solution :)

Comment: @SteveJessop: My comment was an answer to the previous comment (hence the @LewsTherin), meaning that it is not fine just because "Only a copy of the primitive will be made"

Comment: @stefaanv: right, and it's not a problem just because you might refactor `A`. It's a problem if your accessor creates an *inappropriate* property of the object. I don't think even the Law of Demeter people think that `vector` shouldn't have a `size()` function, although I wouldn't be hugely surprised if I've underestimated their ability to follow through on an idea :-) The important point is that the size of a vector is a meaningful concept independent of how `vector` happens to store the size. If the same is true for the `aa` of an `A`, a getter wouldn't break encapsulation.

Comment: @LewsTherin: What is being discussed here is a higher level concept than the actual implementation and language. In particular, C# properties are nice in the sense that they might or might not be backed by a field in the class. Going back to the vector example and Steve's last comment, in C# you can write a property `size` that either returns the stored size, if it is stored, or calculates it somehow. Note that *property* is a higher level concept (design). The size is a read only property of the vector, whether implemented in C# as a *C#-property* or a function in C++.

Answer (score 4):

I see questions like this and I ask why. There'a apparently no relationship between class A and class B beyond that they have an int.

The way to make this compile is to make C a friend of A and B, or at least make the equal function in C a friend of A and B (with careful use of forward declarations).

```
class A;
class B;
class C { static bool equal(A const &, B const &); };
class A { friend bool C::equal(A const &, B const &) };
class B { friend bool C::equal(A const &, B const &) };
bool C::equal(A& const &a, B const &b) { return a.a == b.b; }
```

Please note the const qualifier as it is unlikely that a comparison operator is meant to alter its input. Moreoever I have made it a static function as it doesn't use any of the members of C - it is completely unrelated. (as per your snippet).

Basically - that's how you do it. But don't do it without a LOT of thought. Just because apples and oranges both have pips, doesn't mean there's a lot of point in comparing the numbers of pips.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the classes `friend`s with each other.

But, as pointed out in comments, that's pretty horrible in most cases. The reason the member is `private` has to be because outside parties *shouldn't* access it directly.

So, either add `operator==()` overloads to `A` and  `B` that can be used (i.e. an `bool A::equal(const B&) const;` method), or add accessors to return the value for external comparison.

Comment: Wouldn't this break encapsulation? I would go with accessor methods in this case.

Comment: But then the equality operators would have to be friends.

Answer (score 0):

Form friendship with two classes(c & a , c & b) and then compare.

Answer (score 0):

If they are private and cannot be accessed via any kind of public interface it means conceptually they have nothing in common. so add public `getAA` `getBB` and use it to make the comparator between objects. I dislike friendship. A lot.

Comment: "If they are private and cannot be accessed via any kind of public interface..."  and then: "add public getters". Doesn't this sound at least a bit contradictory to you?

Comment: by adding getter you give an access thus change a previous situation. Why is it contradictory?

Answer (score 0):

You could make `A` and `B` to be friend of `C` or add `int GetVar() const` methods to `A` and `B` classes.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need this?

Combine behaviour with the data.

```
class C
{
public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        if(aa == bb) {
            doThis();
        } else
            doThat();
        }
    }
private:
    int aa;
    int bb;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Without commenting on the relevance of the request, or alternatives for the presumed underlying reason, I believe you can compare private members thru Reflection:

```
FieldInfo AInfo = av.GetType().GetField("aa", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
int AValue = (int) AInfo.GetValue(av);
```

etcetera

Comment: sorry about that, was too hasty translating from one language to another; hope it's better now.